# Trying to fill empty fields by using IS INITAL

Tags: abap

I am trying to update a certain part of the code, where the code is shown below.

```
    READ TABLE lt_cc_data ASSIGNING <ls_cc_data>
    WITH KEY qmnum = ls_refferal-qmnum.
    IF <ls_cc_data>-pruef is INITAL.            *>>>>>Statement that I added
    IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
      <ls_cc_data>-pruef = <ls_ccicons>-icon_id.
    ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
```

Before entering the statement that I have shown in the code, the program would enter in each `qnum = ls_refferal-qmnum` and fill the `pruef` field, however it did not take into account the cases when the `qnum` had the same values throughout the table. What I try to did is filling the `pruef` field only in those cases when the field is empty.

Being that I cannot test it due to lack of data in the development system, is the logic behind my solution correct and if not can someone give me an similar solution?

Thank you all in advance!

---

EDIT
The code would look like this now:

```
 READ TABLE lt_cc_data ASSIGNING <ls_cc_data>
    WITH KEY qmnum = ls_refferal-qmnum.
    IF <ls_cc_data>-pruef is INITAL.            *>>>>>Statement that I added
      <ls_cc_data>-pruef = <ls_ccicons>-icon_id.
    ENDIF.
```

Comment: I don't fully understand, what you want to achieve, but one thing is sure: the two IF statements have to be replaced, first check, whether the READ TABLE was successfull (IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL) and after, whether the field is empty (IF <ls_cc_data>-pruef IS INITIAL).

Comment: Hi @JózsefSzikszai, yes the table was read successfully. Thus if I eliminate the IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL and instead only the second if will be put, like it is shown now on the edit part of the question, then it may be okay?

Comment: The code is worse now, without the check on the sy-subrc. That is necessary, othersie it will dump, if the READ TABLE is not successfull. After that with IF field IS INITIAL means, if the field has no value, it will get a new one (from field icon_id), otherwise it will remain the same.

Comment: "Being that I cannot test it due to lack of data in the development system" What? So you want random strangers on the internet to tell you that your code is correct, so that you can shoot against production? That sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: "throughout the table" ... then why is only one entry read? Wouldn't it make sense to directly filter when reading from the table instead of reading every row and then checking whether it applies?

Comment: Also note that conditions can be combined with OR and AND, and nesting IFs without further statements is unneccessary.